# how to target my classname with queryselectorall

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure why I can't query select my class by using document.querySelectorAll.

I thought at first that it was because they were within two other divs so I commented them out. And, still nothing. Targeting elementsById is no problem. I tested this with just one button and it console.log the button.value.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="heading">
    <h1>Calculator!!!!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div id="calculator" class="calc">
<input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="0">

    <button class="numbers" id= "seven" >7</button>
    <button class="numbers" id= "eight">8</button>
    <button class="numbers"id= "nine">9</button>
    <button class="operator"id= "multiply">*</button>
    <button class="numbers" id= "four">4</button>
    <button class="numbers" id=  "five">5</button>
    <button class="numbers" id= "six">6</button>
    <button class="operator" id= "subtract">-</button>
    <button class="numbers" id= "one">1</button>
    <button class="numbers" id= "two">2</button>
    <button class="numbers" id=  "three">3</button> 
    <button class ="operator" id= "add">+</button>   
    <button class ="operator" id= "divide">/</button>
    
    <button id= "clr ()">C</button>
    <button id ="del ()">DEL</button>
    <button class = "equals" id= "equals">=</button>
</div>
</div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
let currentOperator = null;
let firstOperand = null;
let secondOperand = null;
let toBeCleaned = false;
let result = null;
let display = document.getElementById("userinput");
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");
const calc = document.querySelector(".calc")

const operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
const equalSign = document.getElementById("equal");
const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");



numberButtons.onclick = function () {
    if (numberButtons.className == "numbers") {
        console.log(numberButtons);
    }
}
```

Comment: querySelectorAll works fine. it returns a  [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).  What doesn't work is `numberButtons.onclick`.  You have to iterate through the nodelist and set onclick for each element. Or apply event listeners in some other manner.

Comment: You can simply check if the `querySelectorAll` worked by `console.log(operators)`. You will see that it will return a NodeList with the correct items. You can follow the advice from ippi & Thomas to get the wanted result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` worked fine, but it returns a list of elements rather than a single element. You can't simply set `onclick` on the entire list at once; you'll need to loop through it:

```
numberButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.onclick = function () {
        // Handle button click
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you for this, but now im presented with a new problem. numberButtons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.onclick = function (btn) {
      
        display.placeholder = btn.target.value;
    }
  })  would a for loop let me display multiple numbers. Im summing the forEach is preventing multiple numbers from being displayed

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with querySelectorAll.
QuerySelectorAll returns an array of all found elements.
And you're trying to put an onclick event on the array.
That won't work.

To make onclick work, do this

```
numberButtons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.onclick = function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.target)
  }
})
```